# Easier way to find integers for complex^complex

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, code-request, mathematical-optimization

If I have (a+b I)^(c+d I) and the result is e+f I

a,b,c,d should be integers

e >= 2 or e <= -2

f so close to zero as possible .. this is the object function I want to minimize

How to do this in Mathematica? Something like this below, but I cannot figure it out

```
NMinimize[{function, constraint, constraint, Element[{a,b,c,d}, Integers]}, {a,b,c,d}]
```

Comment: Let a=e, b=0, c=1, d=0 and you have your answer with f=0.

Comment: Thanks. What if I need a,b,c,d >= 2 or a,b,c,d <= -2, so that no -1,0,1 integers are allowed

Comment: Then you should edit the problem to state these constraints.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.  It's also nice if people can copy-paste complete code. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's search explicitly up to $\pm s$:

```
s = 50;
A = Reap[Do[If[Min[Abs[{a, b, c, d}]] >= 2 && 
               Abs[Re[N[(a + b I)^(c + d I)]]] >= 2, 
                 Sow[{a, b, c, d}]],
            {a, -s, s}, {b, -s, s}, {c, -s, s}, {d, -s, s}]][[2, 1]];
B = MinimalBy[A, Abs[Im[N[(#[[1]] + #[[2]] I)^(#[[3]] + #[[4]] I)]]] &]
(*    {{13, -39, 5, -11}, {13, 39, 5, 11}}    *)

(#[[1]] + #[[2]] I)^(#[[3]] + #[[4]] I) & /@ B
(*    {(13 - 39 I)^(5 - 11 I), (13 + 39 I)^(5 + 11 I)}    *)

% // N
(*    {-126.685 + 2.13912*10^-7 I, -126.685 - 2.13912*10^-7 I}    *)
```

### Update

With a C code I've searched up to $s=1024$, getting a speedup of around 80 compared to Mathematica. The best result so far is

```
(533 - 276 I)^(-6 + 85 I) // N
(*    9.29623 - 4.15874*10^-10 I    *)
```

Code:

```c
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void run(const int nmax) {
  double imin = 2;
  for (int a = -nmax; a <= nmax; a++)
    if (abs(a) >= 2)
      for (int b = -nmax; b <= nmax; b++)
        if (abs(b) >= 2) {
          const double complex x = a + I * b;
          for (int c = -nmax; c <= nmax; c++)
            if (abs(c) >= 2)
              for (int d = 2; d <= nmax; d++) {
                const double complex y = c + I * d;
                const double complex z = cpow(x, y);
                if ((fabs(creal(z)) >= 2) && (fabs(cimag(z)) < imin)) {
                  imin = fabs(cimag(z));
                  printf("(%d,%d,%d,%d) --> %g + I * %g\n",
                         a, b, c, d,
                         creal(z), cimag(z));
                }
              }
        }
}

int main() {
  run(1024);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Save as `complex.c`, compile with

```
gcc complex.c -lm -O3 -o complex
```

and run with

```
./complex
```

### A bit of analysis

Here's an incomplete analysis of a possible way forward.

We are looking for numbers $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $(a+i b)^{c+i d}$ has a small imaginary part. This means that $\arg[(a+i b)^{c+i d}]\approx n\pi$ for an integer value $n$:
$$
\arg[(a+i b)^{c+i d}]=
c \arg(a+i b)+d\ln\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\approx n\pi, n\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
For given integer values of $(a,b)$ we can therefore calculate the values $\gamma=\frac{\arg(a+i b)}{\pi}=\frac{\tan^{-1}(b/a)}{\pi}$ and $\delta=\frac{\ln\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\pi}=\frac{\ln(a^2+b^2)}{2\pi}$, and then try to find integers $(c,d)$ such that $c\gamma+d\delta$ is as close to an integer as possible.

I don't know how to do this in practice but it sounds like a typical numerical math problem. I've tried using [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) and [`ContinuedFraction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuedFraction.html) to convert $(\gamma,\delta)$ to rationals and setting $(c,d)$ as their respective denominators; but there were no good results coming out of this approach. Maybe someone else will have a better idea for going forward.

Comment: Surperb.    Two things come to mind:  (1)  How long did it take in C compared to interpreted,  and (2)  Is it possible to prove that your value may be the smallest value?

Comment: Please see update. C is about 80 times faster than Mathematica. As for proving, I'd assume that there is no smallest value and as the search space expands we'll find ever smaller values.

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  So your hypothesis may be stated as $$
\lim_{s\to\infty}\text{min Im} (a+bi)^{(c+di)}\to 0;\quad (a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash \{-2,-1,0,1,2\}
$$  I'll look at it a while and if I can't come up with something, I may propose it at the Mathematics forum.  For example, is there a way to find them in a s-4D hypercube other than an exhaustive search?

Comment: Thank you both ! The compile command could have -lm in the end of command line to avoid "undefined reference cpow" error message.

Comment: In my original question (a,b,c,d) must not be {-1, 0, 1} but 2 and -2 would be ok. But I am ok with any limit. This is something like: how real the result could be if we raise complex^complex so that there is no {-1,0,1} coeffs ..

Answer (score 3):

Having a little problem installing C on my machine but here's a way to improve the exhaustive search performance using Mathematica:  Once we have the min for $s$, and wish to find the min for $s+ds$, we do not need to check the entire $s+ds$ space but rather only the outer shells of the hypercube. The following routine searches the six outer coverings of the hypercube (consider a picture frame around a picture.  The frame is the outer coverings.  Now extend this to 4D):

```
computeCover[cover_, s_, dt_] := Module[{coverRanges, regionData},
   coverRanges = {
     {{-s - dt, s + dt}, {-s - dt, s + dt}, {s, s + dt}},
     {{-s - dt, s + dt}, {-s - dt, s + dt}, {-s - dt, -s}},
     {{s, s + dt}, {-s - dt, s + dt}, {-s, s}},
     {{-s - dt, -s}, {-s - dt, s + dt}, {-s, s}},
     {{-s, s}, {-s - dt, -s}, {-s, s}},
     {{-s, s}, {s, s + dt}, {-s, s}}
     };
   regionData = Reap[
      Do[
       If[
        Min[Abs[{a, b, c, d}]] >= 2 && 
         Abs[Re[N[(a + b I)^(c + d I)]]] >= 2,
        Sow[{a, b, c, d, Abs@Im[(a + b I)^(c + d I)] // N}]],
       {d, -s, s},
       {a, coverRanges[[cover, 1, 1]], coverRanges[[cover, 1, 2]]},
       {b, coverRanges[[cover, 2, 1]], coverRanges[[cover, 2, 2]]},
       {c, coverRanges[[cover, 3, 1]], coverRanges[[cover, 3, 2]]}
       ]
      ][[2, 1]];
   MinimalBy[regionData, 
    Abs[Im[N[(#[[1]] + #[[2]] I)^(#[[3]] + #[[4]] I)]]] &]
   ];
```

And we can therefore parallel-process the six covers given an $s$ and $ds$.  Take for example we've already determined that the min for $s=10$ are:

```
coreVals={{-9, -5, 3, -2, 0.00309571}, {-9, 5, 3, 2, 0.00309571}}
```

and wish to determing the min for $s=15$:  Now parallel-process the six covers $(s,ds)=(10,5)$ and compute the minimum of the coreVals and covers:

```
AbsoluteTiming[theResults = ParallelTable[computeCover[index, 10, 5],
    {index, 1, 6}
    ];
 ]
MinimalBy[Join[coreVals, Flatten[theResults, 1]], #[[5]] &]


 (* {4.5464, Null} *)
    
   (* {{3, -15, 5, -9, 0.0000800848}, {3, 15, 5, 9, 0.0000800848}} *)
```

And compare this $4.5$ second execution time to a explicit search for $s=15$ which takes about $14$ seconds:

```
s2 = 15;
coverTime = AbsoluteTiming[A = Reap[
     Do[
      If[Min[Abs[{a, b, c, d}]] >= 2 && 
        Abs[Re[N[(a + b I)^(c + d I)]]] >= 2,
       Sow[{a, b, c, d, Abs@Im[(a + b I)^(c + d I)] // N}]],
      {a, -s2, s2},
      {b, -s2, s2},
      {c, -s2, s2},
      {d, -s2, s2}
      ]
     ][[2, 1]];
  B = MinimalBy[A, 
    Abs[Im[N[(#[[1]] + #[[2]] I)^(#[[3]] + #[[4]] I)]]] &];
  theVals = (#[[1]] + #[[2]] I)^(#[[3]] + #[[4]] I) & /@ B;
  ]
theVals // N
B
coverTime[[1]]

(* {13.9903, Null} *)

(* {{3, -15, 5, -9, 0.0000800848}, {3, 15, 5, 9, 0.0000800848}} *)
```

Which is about $3.5$ times faster.  And once the routine is converted to C, even without parallel-processing, the overall performance could be increased even more.